# Can't switch Docker context

Tags: docker

I have created new Docker context and I am trying to switch to it from the default, but even tho it says it have switched, it has not switched. I always get the same warning "Current context is now "ryukote-docker-server"
Warning: DOCKER_HOST environment variable overrides the active context. To use "ryukote-docker-server", either set the global --context flag, or unset DOCKER_HOST environment variable." I don't know what should I do with this. I have tried to change the value of DOCKER_HOST environment variable but it doesn't work.

I have also tried using DOCKER_CONTEXT environment variable but default context is still selected.

Answer (score 1):

If the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable is set, it always takes precedence over any `docker context`.

When the error message says "unset DOCKER_HOST", it literally means that: [**unset**(1)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_29) is a special shell built-in, and you need to run

```bash
unset DOCKER_HOST
```

Comment: unset is not Windows command. Is there alternative for it?

Comment: Oh, I have managed to find the answer. I have found on StackOverflow that I need to run "chmod o+rw /var/run/docker.sock" on Docker server PC and now I can access it

Comment: That's a major security mistake, and opens your machine up to any local process being able to compromise the entire system via Docker.

Comment: David, that is not an issue for me. I am here to learn by an example.